# Erratic fps from VideoCapture opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, video-capture

I get the fps from video files using opencv.
It works well for all videos that I have, except those videos recorded by my phone (samsung note). I am getting fps=90000 by calling VideoCapture::get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS) for. I verified the properties of video files taken by phone, they seem that no problem with recorded files (fps = 30), but when I get fps by opencv its erratic value!

Does any get this problem? any suggestion?

EDIT:

```
VideoCapture input_video("20.mp4"); // here I read a file, recorded by cameraphone
double fps=input_video.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS); 
cout<<fps<<endl; // prints 90000 !!!!!
// continue without problem
```

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: there are codecs out there with a variable framerate(imho, you're getting bogus values due to this). others even don't support querying CV_CAP_PROP_FPS at all. it's not a mandatory feature, so don't rely on it too heavily.